# Is it acceptable to decrease the HP rating of a blank-face GFCI?

Tags: electrical, gfci

I have a 20 amp Blank Face GFCI rated at 1.5HP that is protecting two outdoor 15 amp receptacles. Could I use a 1hp blank face GFCI instead? Also, why wouldn't the electrician used a regular gfci instead?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure that it's no powering more than those two recepticles?

Yes, you can downgrade it from 1.5 to 1.  You SHOULD however, make sure the new GFCI you want to install is rated for 20 Amps.

As for why they chose a dead front, most likely it was used for a spa at some point and local code forbid use for anything else.

It could also have been that the owner intended to reserve its capacity for some other high current device.

Some deadfronts have multiple load terminals which could possibly be a reason.  (To avoid wire nuts).

Or perhaps it's a 240v GFCI.  Nobody generally has use for 240v 20A outlets.

Comment: Thank you very much. Definitely was not used for a spa or anything like that. Its in the basement right beside the electrical panel. 100% sure it only powers two outside 15amp receptacles.

Comment: My thought was that perhaps at some point in the past, there was a spa/hottub outside, and it was removed, at which time the outlets were added.  It's really anyone's guess why its deadfront, but that could be one reason to do it that way for some people.  I would personally want to put the gfci outside with the spa/outlets, so you don't have to walk 200 feet to check/reset it.